# The new Stack Overflow logo is blurry

Tags: bug, design, logo

Here is a screenshot from zoomed in Paint.NET where I pasted a screenshot taken using the Windows Snipping Tool. The browser is Chrome and it was not zoomed.

[image]

Machine info:

- Chrome 46 beta
- Windows 7 x64
- Browser not zoomed
- Nothing special that I can think of
- Reproduces with FF as well

Comment: The devs can fix that. Not sure how to fix that with SVG but it would be easy to fix with a normal pixel-based image. With SVG the logo probably needs to be nudged by a fraction of a pixel.

Comment: we're aware of it. we're fixing it. the problem was caused by the dimension in svg has decimal values instead of whole number in pixels. so browser can't pixel snap it.

Comment: @Jin you are restoring my sanity.

Comment: @Jin: TIL: SVG *can* have antialiasing issues when rendered at smaller scales.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes. that's the problem with SVGs when used in small size. For logo use, if we make the svg at the exact dimension(1:1 scale) we want then it'd look fine. We did it with our old logo svg that just got replaced.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: It's a pretty common problem. It's why it's often recommended - particularly for non-trivial icons - that their lo-res images be redrawn rather than just use scaled-down vectors. Saying it's a bug in the rendering is like saying the reason an HD video looks terrible on a CRT is because of a bug in the CRT technology.

Comment: @BoltClock the CRT is outside the control of the devs. Pictures on the web are controllable. When I told my clients that I cannot fix their blurry logo because it is "SVG" they would not have it.

Comment: @boot4life: I was referring to his comment on it being a bug in the rendering of your machine - which is outside of the control of the devs as well.

Comment: @Jin: Can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: The golden favorite star (in SVG) seems to be damaged as well or is that micro optimization?

Comment: what is wrong with a simple ol' png or jpg? why complicate things?

Comment: @mxmissile because of high-res displays. Raster images would look worse on these.

Comment: @mxmissile: probably because that looks blurry on Retina displays then

Comment: I think the guys at [PCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) should brute-force the best solution in a code-golf competition

Comment: @mxmissile - It's much more important that the minority of users with crazy high resolution screens have a crisp image than those with low resolution screens. If they wanted good looking pixels, they would have bought more pixels. I jest, of course. Obviously if you're making new graphics, you may as well make those graphics look nice when rendered on newer screens that will likely be standard someday.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: [We already did](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/generate-the-stack-overflow-logo), although that was for the old logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jin, the designer of Stack Overflow, is aware of the problem. It will be fixed.

> Jin: we're aware of it. we're fixing it. the problem was caused by the dimension in svg has decimal values instead of whole number in pixels. so browser can't pixel snap it

Comment: Can browsers apply hinting to SVG images? Because if they can't it will either look bad at 96dpi, or it will look bad at 120dpi.