# The yellow star in the sprites.svg image looks "unfinished"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images, bookmarks

*(Probably one cannot come up with a more irrelevant, bike-shedding bug report than this one)*

The favorite question star in the [sprites.svg](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg) image has an outline that does not align with the content:

[image: Yellow favorite question star]

The upper left and lower left sides have some empty areas shine through.

**My suggestion:**

Make the border and content of the star align correctly on all sides.

Comment: __Outrageous!__

Comment: Oh, the red circle with a white cross in it is also [in there](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg), ___twice___.

Comment: @CRABOLO Yeah, my browser crashes all the time because of this severe bug.

Comment: Rating the guy who designed that with *1 star* out of 5. -_-

Comment: Actually, [both standing borders](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4jXep.png) are crooked.

Comment: Too late - I noticed that [two days before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306174/the-new-stack-overflow-logo-is-blurry#comment248158_306174). I guess Jin is aware of it.

Comment: It was probably that darn [crayon wielding kid](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

Comment: I guess those who star this question want to check it more quickly. Nice idea :)

Comment: I guess the best way to get loads of upvotes would be to find a bug in the upvote icon...

Comment: _Toggles star to see if the bug is fixed when I look here_

Comment: How does one even spot a bug like this?

Comment: @Cerbrus There are others as well.

Comment: *Why is this not fixed yet?!*

Comment: 6 to 8 months @AndrasDeak

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Eww, that looks as if somebody just took a bitmap image and fed it through a vector tracer without bothering to check the results (or redraw it properly).

Here's a nice hand-optimized pair of SVG stars to replace them with:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="30">
<path d="M17.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0"/>
<path d="M57.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z" fill="#ffd83d" stroke="#eac328"/>
</svg>
```

[image: illustration]

<sup>They're even scaled and spaced properly for dropping directly into the SE sprite sheet.  Just remember to offset them 120px from the top.</sup>

And here's a bit of user CSS to replace the current wonky stars with the SVG image above:

```css
body .star-off, body .star-on {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20width='80'%20height='30'%3E%3Cpath%20d='M17.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z'%20fill='%23c0c0c0'%20stroke='%23c0c0c0'/%3E%3Cpath%20d='M57.5,12.5h-8.5l6.8,5-2.6,8.1,6.8-5,6.8,5-2.6-8.1,6.8-5h-8.5l-2.6-8.1z'%20fill='%23ffd83d'%20stroke='%23eac328'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: 30px; width: 40px;
}
body .star-off { background-position: 0px 0px }
body .star-on { background-position: -40px 0px }
```

Comment: *This* is how minor 'bug' reports should be answered. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

This is now fixed, thanks for the catch. Looks like something corrupted during sprite compression.