# not important - bounty reason and close/flag post popup view left hand side not visible when really zoomed in

Tags: bug, flags, design, bounty, popup

> (Probably one cannot come up with a more irrelevant, bike-shedding bug report than this one) - [Uwe Keim](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim), [question link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306325/the-yellow-star-in-the-sprites-svg-image-looks-unfinished)

While investigating Uwe's bug I found another one. Firefox (latest vers), Win8.1. Zoomed in 300%. I tried starting a bounty just to see if there would be any buggies. The first popup view shows fine, but after deciding on the amount to bounty and clicking next, the bounty reason popup view starts left of left field. Looks like it affects all/most sites.

[image]

[image]

---

*It also does it for the close **and** flag popups. Comment flags look great though.*

[image]